# I want to add some space in my HTML output

Tags: sql, rstudio

I need some space between the RANK and STATE columns so that the information is not confusing, please do let me know: I am posting my query below,

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS  LGBRANDRANK 

AS 

SELECT  Brand_Name,Rank () Over (Order by Brand_Name) as BrandNameRank, 

Vend_state as State, Strftime("%m",Inv_Date) as WeekNumber,StrfTime("%Y",Inv_Date) as YearOfSales,  Sum(INV_Total) As WeeklyTotalSales from LGPRODUCT 

inner join LGSUPPLIES on LGPRODUCT.Prod_SKU = LGSUPPLIES.Prod_SKU 

inner join LGLINE on LGLINE.Prod_SKU = LGPRODUCT.Prod_SKU

inner join LGINVOICE on LGLINE.Inv_Num = LGINVOICE.Inv_Num

inner join LGVENDOR on LGSUPPLIES.Vend_ID = LGVENDOR.Vend_ID

inner join LGBRAND on LGBRAND.Brand_ID = LGPRODUCT.Brand_ID


group by Weeknumber, BRAND_NAME
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unclear how rstudio has anything to do with this

Comment: I am still a beginner so I have no comments just looking for a solution if I can get one. because I used Str_Pad but it says there is no such function.

Comment: if you want an empty column you can add `'' as " "`in the select list. If you to add spaces at the beginning or end of a column you can concatenate spaces. The syntax of concatenation varies with the rdbms, often `concat(string1, string2` or `string1 || string2`